# Huge amount of data to write works in old Windows Server 2003 but not in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sending a huge amount of data to write on a line in SQL Server table via web service C#.

I have a web service running on an old machine with MS Windows Server 2003 SP2 that works perfect. Write the expected values in the database, and write log OK in the same DB.

The same web service working on two different machines but Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard does not show any error writes OK in the log in DB, however does not write the line to the table.

My application has no attempt to catch errors so it should crash if this error.

Any idea?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You seem to imply that no attempt to catch errors is an advantage. You would probably have a good idea of the problem if you had Exception handling. My wild guess is protocol  negotiation - maybe the newer server only allows TLS 1.2 and your app is on an older .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

To write a huge amount of data into a single line is actually NOT a good practice. BUT, instead of that, if still you want to do same then, YES you will face problem with this write. I have also faced this type of issue while SQL script automation where i was preparing a dynamic huge query and saving it to the variable.

You can take it as a bug in SQL server that when you assign a huge string to a variable then after specific character length it starts behaving very odd. Sometime there will be no data into the variable or sometime only truncated data with the random character length. The big issue is this only, that in such cases it doesn't fails.

**Solution -** If you can change your web service then break the huge data into the max string length under 4000 and pass the same to you DB table to store. And continuously append the next data set into same line.

OR, use a explicit C# code in-between your data transaction when data is moving from web service to DB, to break it in same fashion as described above.